# Android intent filter for notes

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm searching for the intent-filter that my Note App can catch if, for example Google now wantS to save a Note. I know that Google Keep and GTask kann catch these, but wHich is it?

Answer (score 1):

Have it:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.gm.action.AUTO_SE ND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

and in code with

```
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.T EXT");
```